# Google V3 API for commentThreads

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have to get all the commentThreads of a channel to all videos after a certain timestamp, similar to how there is "publishedAfter" request parameter in the V3 Activities API. Is there any way to do that (direct or workaround)?
My requirement is to have a scheduled job retrieving all the activities of a channel periodically - this includes new videos, and new comments on old videos. I don't think using allThreadsRelatedToChannelId alone would be a good idea since it could be a lot of pre-existing redundant data.

Any thoughts?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and final confirmation from someone from Google, I can say for sure that there is no way of getting comments "pblishedAfter" a certain time in the current released version of the API.